# jQuery adds inArray as last array/object element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have noticed that in some cases, when `jQuery` is imported, it adds as last element of defined object or array - `inArray` ... that totally ruins `for ... in` loop, because it counts that stupid function as element.

Example:

```
console.log(v);
VM19135:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not defined
var v = [];
console.log(v);
VM19222:2 [inArray: function]
```

What the hell???? How to avoid that?

Here's an example site that gives those results:
http://kobieta.interia.pl

Just enter console, and type:

var v = [];
console.log(v);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) when you run into this problem. This happens because of the way JavaScript uses prototypes.

It's annoying but you will need to run your for-in loop similar to this:

```
var v = [];
for (var name in v) {
  if (v.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    console.log(v[name]);
  }
}
```